# Xcode 8.3 breaks my app

Tags: ios, xcode8

The official release of Xcode 8.3 causes my app to freeze completely after an apparently random amount of time. It also causes network connections to never finish (which may be the reason for the eventual freeze? A deadlock waiting for some resources to be released maybe?).

The exact same code works fine when compiled with Xcode 8.2.1.

Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: I experienced something similar. Not related to building but to archiving. Some functionality in the release version (e.g. using NMSSH to connect via SSH) was failing all the time. After archiving with Xcode 8.2.1 it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the problem is related to the use of this kind of construct:

```
@discardableResult func synchronized<T>(_ lock: Any, closure: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    defer {
        objc_sync_exit(lock)
    }
    return try closure()
}
```

Replacing this with Matt Gallagher's PThreadMutex (https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlUtils) fixes the issue.

I hope it isn't a deliberate move by Apple to push people off the Obj-C runtime, because if it is, it's definitely a sneaky way to do it, and pretty inconsiderate on their part given how widespread the use of the above construct probably is. If they don't want people to use those, then they should provide thread synchronization services in Swift instead of completely ignoring the need. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8.3.1 is now available.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04062017a

> Due to the resolved app archives issue listed below, we will soon be
>   deprecating Xcode 8.3, at which time app archives built with Xcode 8.3
>   will no longer be accepted by the App Store.

Try updating the xcode as there are a number of issues in previous version.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy for me. Same behaviour with Xcode 8.3.1

Comment: Are you able to build the app ?

Comment: Yes, sure, I can build the app, it kinda runs for a while, then freezes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble yesterday, too.

It was posted on Apple Developer Forms on April 25th that the app archives built with Xcode 8.3 will no longer be accepted by the App Store.

Title:Please update from Xcode 8.3 to Xcode 8.3.1 or later
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/225571#225571